# How to create Custom module in HUMhub open source social networking site?

Tags: php, python, yii, yii2, social-networking

I'm working with [Humhub](https://www.humhub.org/en) Open source Social networking Kit and i want to create a new module for it.

I referred [this](https://www.humhub.org/docs/guide-dev-module.html) from the documentation but i was unable to understand how to create a module for Humhub.

Is there Any tutorial with example for creating modules in Humhub ? If Not Can anyone suggest the steps of creating the module?

Hope someone recognizes the problem and has a quick solution for it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best "documentation" that I have found so far are two examples on GitHub that seem to work. You can find them here:

https://github.com/humhub/humhub-modules-examples

The humhub-modules-**basic**-module-dummy and the humhub-modules-**content**-module-dummy do what they are meant to do. The basic module puts a menu item at the top and shows a simple page with some content and the content module shows the module option in the users modules (if configured by the admin to do so). It is interesting how much code it takes to do these things, especially compared to the standard Yii2 code generated by Gii. But they do work, and so offer a starting point for further development.

Also, for some basic documentation, there is a write-up on the HumHub documentation page here:

http://docs.humhub.org/dev-modules-db.html

However, it is very incomplete as of this date. But it may provide a bit of insight when used with the examples mentioned above.